# ALB -> multiple containers running on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a service which consists of two different containers, let's just call them the API and Worker containers. I want to configure my Beanstalk application so that I can run multiple instances of the API container but only one Worker.

I need to each API container to use a unique host port (obviously) and I need my ALB to automatically route to these ports automatically.

I need to do this from Elastic Beanstalk instead of directly in ECS. Also, I have one reserved instance which I want to leverage so I'd like to force Beanstalk to place multiple copies of my API container on this instance (binpack). . .

This is all fairly straightforward to do without Elastic Beanstalk, that is, going through ECS directly, can it be done with Beanstalk or am I crazy?